# Calculate the arclength

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, recursion, numerical-methods

I am trying to estimate a good approximation for the arclength of the curve \$ y = \sqrt{1-x^2}\$ for \$x \in [0, 1]\$. I did this using a Bezièr curve, and made it so that the area under the two curves are alike. In order to estimate the error I want to calculate the differences in arclength. The arclength of a quarter circle is \$\frac14\pi\$ so it boils down to estimating

$$\mathrm{Difference}= \frac{L - \frac12\pi}{\frac12\pi}$$

Where \$L\$ is the arclength of my Bezièr curve. The problem, or rather my question is how to find a good method for estimating this arclength.

I tried using recursion and the Pythagorean theorem. I calculate the distance between \$P\$ and \$Q\$. Then I calculate the distances \$PR\$ and \$QR\$, where \$R\$ lies between \$P\$ and \$Q\$. If \$\mathrm{abs}( d(PR) + d(QR) - d(PQ)) < \mathrm{Error}\$ I return the length \$d(PR) + d(QR)\$.

This is painfully slow. Setting `digits = 15` takes about 30 seconds on my computer and `digits = 16` takes about a minute.

**Have I implemented this method incorrectly, or in a highly inefficient way?**

```
from decimal import *
import decimal
from math import pi
getcontext().prec = 100


nu = 2-(66-15*pi)**0.5/float(3)

def bezier(t):
    f = (1-t)**3 + 3*(1-t)**2*t + 3*(1-t)*t**2*nu
    g = 3*(1-t)**2*t*nu + 3*(1-t)*t**2 + t**3
    return (f, g)


def arc_length(start_t = 0, stop_t = 1, error = 10**(-6), length = 0):
    mean_t = 0.5*(start_t + stop_t)
    P = bezier(start_t)
    Q = bezier(mean_t)
    R = bezier(stop_t)

    length_one = decimal.Decimal(pyt(P, Q))
    length_two = decimal.Decimal(pyt(Q, R))
    if abs(length_one + length_two - length) < error:
        return length_one + length_two
    else:
        return arc_length(start_t, mean_t, error, length_one) + arc_length(mean_t, stop_t, error, length_two)


def pyt(P, Q):
    return ((P[0] - Q[0])**2 + (P[1] - Q[1])**2)**0.5


if __name__ == '__main__':

    digits = 5
    error = 10**(-digits)
    t1 = 0
    t2 = 1
    length = arc_length(0, 1, error)
    print length
    diff = (length - decimal.Decimal(pi)/decimal.Decimal(2))/(decimal.Decimal(pi)/decimal.Decimal(2))
    print diff
```

Comment: You might want to look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195116/python-decimal) for performance of `Decimal`.

Comment: Wow moving decimal out of the recursion made a huge speedimprovement. Who could have guessed?

Comment: Why do you import decimal twice? I think you dont need the **from decimal import * ** since you already have import decimal.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to compute \$\sqrt{1 - x^2}\$, why not use `sqrt(1 - x**2)`? Are you actually trying to compute something else, for example the arc length of the curve \$y=\sqrt{1 - x^2}\$? Why are you using decimal when you only want 15 digits of precision? Please update the question so it is clear what you are trying to compute and why.

Comment: Updated =) \$ {} \$

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I don't understand the question either. The arc length of a function in a given interval is a constant number, what's the point of constructing the bezier curve and doing all sorts of calculations?

Comment: The Bezier curve is an attempt at approximating that number as closely as possible using a smoother curve.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar again: it is a **constant number**. Whatever you are doing, replace it by that number.

Comment: Once again `sqrt(1-x^2)` is a **test case**, in order to check how well the bezier curve behaves. I could easilly have made it `sqrt( 1-x^3)` or some other function where the arclength is not known.....

Comment: I understood what you wanted, so it was clear to me. But, as I hinted: it would be more obvious that you want `arc_length` to work for any curve if you make `bezier` a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

## weird function name `pyth`

Did you mean pythagoras? Oh, no, you meant `distance`.

## what does `bezier` do?

What are f,g? It looks like it returns two values based on `t`, but it is not clear to me what the expressions signify. How did you get those expressions?

It probably derives somehow from `f(x) = sqrt(1-x^2)` and its derivatives.

Maybe it would help if you could show us what the code looks like for the arclength of the arc formed by `f(x) = 1` between -1 and 1 (it should return 2).

## arc length algorithm

Also, the arc-length runs the risk of running into a recursion-error. And it's slow due to function calls.

Suggested implementation (typed on phone, untested):

```
def arclength(f, low, high, error):
    p_low, p_high = f(low), f(high)
    length = 0
    todo = [(low, high, p_low, p_high, distance(p_low, p_high))]

    while todo:
        segment = todo.pop()
        middle = (segment[0] + segment[1])/2
        p_middle = f(middle)
        d_left = distance(p_middle, segment[2])
        d_right = distance(p_middle, segment[3])

        if abs(d_left + d_right - segment[4]) < error:
            length += d_left + d_right
        else:
            todo.append((low, middle, p_low, p_middle, d_left))
            todo.append((middle, high, p_middle, p_high, d_right))

    return length
```

This has the following invariants on `todo`

- all tuples are of the form `(t0, t1, f(t0), f(t1), distance(f(t0), f(t1)))`.
- at each iteration, a segment is split in two
- if the change in value from splitting up is small enough, the resulting length is added to `length`
- else: the separate segments are both added back to `todo`.

(The `f` is in this case `bezier`, this allows you to replace it with other curve-defining functions like `(cos(t), sin(t))`)